# Is it possible to catch the moment of waking up?

Tags: consciousness

Brian Magee, a British philosopher, begins his autobiography by a question that possessed him as a child - why could he not be aware of falling asleep; the actual moment of the onset of sleep evaded him (he notes too, that this question did not interest his sister).

The contrary question is also just as possible - to catch the moment of wakening; what would it be like to experience: would it be seeing light, before it is light? Is such an experience actually possible?

Comment: From personal experience, there is one particular scenario where I manage to catch perfectly the moment of waking up: I will be having a dream that is very vivid but with logical inconsistencies (for example I will be dreaming that I having a conversation with my current US colleagues but in my old classroom in Tunisia), and then I realize that something is amiss and this must be a dream, as soon as I realize that this must be a dream, I wake up

Comment: @AlexanderSKing, you are describing a classic switch into lucid dreaming. There are various techniques to prevent or at least postpone said waking up, and to increase the likelihood of making that realization in a given night.

Comment: @Alexander S King But do you actually "catch" the moment or simply recall at which point the dream was interrupted? I had something like this in reverse, counting to fall asleep and then remembering the last number counted. But I am not sure that "catches the moment". Some (e.g. Bergson) believe that casting internal experiences in spatial terms, like moments, is altogether a "rational reconstruction".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is sort of possible through the practice of [Lucid dreaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream).

You can experience both falling asleep into dream sleep and waking up from dream sleep.

From my personal experience, falling asleep feels like a roller coaster or an earth quake of the senses, in particular with a lot of noise. Then things become quiet and when you next open your eyes you may find yourself in your dream world.

Waking up is usually more gentle, possibly with the visual field momentarily turning black right before waking up.

Some people report momentarily experiencing the famous sleep paralysis before finally waking up.

If you are interested in the moment of losing and gaining consciousness then that is probably not it, since consciousness is maintained throughout the process.

There is a very interesting phenomenon related to waking up, called [false awakening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_awakening), in which the brain induces one to believe he has woken up, when in fact it is merely the onset of a new dream. Bertrand Russell reports such an experience in one of his books.

The experience of becoming conscious within dream sleep is very interesting in itself. Particularly in the first several times that it happens, it is a moment of great wonder and exhilaration, akin to a powerful spiritual experience.

Richard Feynman recounts his experience with Lucid Dreaming in his book *Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!* In particular he writes that his motivation was exactly to catch the moment of falling asleep:

> After I had written the theme I continued to be curious, and I kept practicing this watching myself as I went to sleep. One night, while I was having a dream, I realized I was observing myself in the dream. I had gotten all the way down into the sleep itself!

The practice of Lucid dreaming is a lot of fun, but note that it may come at the cost of disturbing your habits and patterns of sleeping, and may therefore affect your health.

Comment: +1: interesting stuff! I'd forgotten that Feynman had mentioned this in his book.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to go as far as lucid dreaming.  Jungians in training are sometimes schooled to record their dreams, especially incomplete ones, upon waking.  As you train yourself to do something explicitly upon waking, you become more aware of the exact moment of waking.  Most people find that it is a sensation that you have, but do not focus closely enough to perceive.

Even if you are waking within a dream, you can identify the point at which you are no longer physically paralyzed, and have the ability to act.  Eventually, you can identify the point where you are still physically paralyzed, but no longer 'mentally paralyzed' and are free to make decisions that are not dictated by your passivity or by the context of your mindset in the dream.  This point really exists, even if you never reach the point where you can achieve freedom to act within a dream.